# How to correctly UNNEST this array in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table like the one below:

```
| year | week_number | first_week_day | last_week_day |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2019 |     1       |   2019-01-01   | 2019-01-07    |
.......................................................
```

I have searched for ways to do it and decided to use EXTRACT and GENERATE_DATE. If there is a better way, please advise me.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#StandardSQL
WITH

  dates_2018 AS
(SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2018-01-01", "2018-12-31") AS d_2018)

 ,dates_2019 AS
(SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31") AS d_2019)


SELECT un

FROM dates_2018, UNNEST(d_2018) AS un
--  ,timestamps_2018 AS
-- (SELECT TIMESTAMP(dates_2018) AS timestamps_2018
-- FROM UNNEST(dates_2018))

--  ,d_2018 AS
-- (SELECT EXTRACT(year from timestamps_2018) AS year
--       ,EXTRACT(week from timestamps_2018) AS week
--       ,EXTRACT(day from timestamps_2018) AS day
-- FROM timestamps_2018)

-- SELECT *

-- FROM timestamps_2018
```

My issue now lies to the fact that I can't correct UNNEST the array d_2018, so I can cast all the elements AS timestamps so I can later on extract stuff from them.

When I am unnesting it only returns the first row.

Mainly I am looking for this unnesting fix, but if someone can give any more advise, it will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are breaking the data apart for each year.  From what you describe:

```
WITH dates AS (
      SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2019-12-31') as date_array
     )
select extract(year from d) as year, d,
       EXTRACT(week from d) as week,
       date_trunc(d, week) as first_week_day,
       date_add(date_trunc(d, week), interval 6 day) as last_week_day
from dates cross join
     unnest(date_array) d
ORDER BY d;
```

Comment: I was doing it to test for 2018 first and then for the rest. But you did some nice magic over here that I will have to study. It works great anyways, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`UNNEST` turns array entries into table rows so you can run SQL on them.
I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you can totally do something like

```sql
SELECT 
 d,
 extract(WEEK from d) CW,
 extract(DAY from d) day,
 extract(YEAR from d) year
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2018-01-01", "2019-12-31")) AS d
```

where you feed the array coming from `generate_date_array()` into `unnest()`

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day) AS year,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM day) + 1 AS week_number,
  DATE_TRUNC(day, WEEK) AS first_week_day,
  DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(day, week), INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS last_week_day
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2019-12-31')) AS day
```